# using If/Else statement in ReactJs to return a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Here is **courseButton.jsx**:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import { MenuFoldOutlined, MenuUnfoldOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

export default (props) => {
  const { collapsed, onClick } = props;

  return <>{collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined}</>;
};
```

Both of my components have the same props. So I want to avoid coding like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import { MenuFoldOutlined, MenuUnfoldOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

export default (props) => {
  const { collapsed, onClick } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {collapsed ? (
        <MenuUnfoldOutlined className={styles.trigger} onClick={onClick} />
      ) : (
        <MenuFoldOutlined className={styles.trigger} onClick={onClick} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

So how I can give the selected component the style in one line code.

I want something like [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-trigger-ant-design-demo-4fhlp?file=/index.js:1294-1362).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution scales better as we assign props only once.

```
export default (props) => {
  const { collapsed, onClick } = props;
  const Component = collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined;
  return <Component className={styles.trigger} onClick={onClick} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to keep your code *DRY*. You can store your props in a variable to keep it reusable.

```
export default (props) => {
    const {collapsed, onClick} = props;

    const genericProps = {
       className: styles.trigger,
       onClick,
    }

    if (collapsed) {
       return <MenuUnfoldOutlined {...genericProps} />
    }

    return <MenuFoldOutlined {...genericProps} />
}
```

**Note**: React Fragment is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write it like this:

```
import React from "react"
import styles from "./styles.module.scss"
import {MenuFoldOutlined, MenuUnfoldOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons'


export default (props) => {
    const {collapsed, onClick} = props

    return (
        <>
            {collapsed ? <MenuUnfoldOutlined {...props} /> : <MenuFoldOutlined {...props}/>}
        </>
    )
}
```

- This is the same as writing .
  If the wrapping component has a bunch of props and you only need specific props you can try the following approach:

  export default (props) => {
          // If props has a bunch of props but we only need collapsed and
          // onClick:
          const {collapsed, onClick} = props
          const menuProps = {collapsed, onClick}

  ```
      return (
          <>
              {collapsed ? <MenuUnfoldOutlined {...menuProps} /> : <MenuFoldOutlined {...menuProps}/>}
          </>
      )
  }
  ```